# RxJS - split the array and emit when specific count is reached

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs, vue-rx

I am new to RxJS. I have specific array which I am using the Observable.

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
```

I want to handle the back pressure and handle 3 elements everytime.

I want to split this up like this and emit:

```
[a,b,c] [d,e,f] [g,h]
```

I am using bufferCount(3) for this. But the problem with bufferCount is this it does emit the last interval. As the last interval has only 2 elements in it.

This is my sample code

```
from(streamOfArr$).pipe(
         flatMap(somefunc()),
         bufferCount(3),
         tap((x) => {
                    console.log('3', x);
                }),
         flatMap(somefunc1()),
```

How can I emit the last interval in bufferCount.

Comment: Have you considered the condition under which a buffer emission should occur? (i.e. how can you be sure there's nothing after item `h`?) That said, one possible solution would be to set up a [`buffer()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/buffer) with an inner observable which emits if either: 1) three items are received, 2) some arbitrary timeout is exceeded via [`timer()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer).

Comment: @miqh Is it possible to know the array length and check if how many remaining items are left in the array which are not emitted and if they are less than buffermaxSize. Then the bufferMaxSize might get set remaining items in the array or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is another problem here.

If you see this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-3jwznz

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs'; 
import { bufferCount } from 'rxjs/operators';


const source = from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]).pipe(
  bufferCount(3)
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

You will see that bufferCount emits the last interval (even if the last one has only 2).
Are you sure your source observable is completing?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `bufferCount` you might want to check `mergeAll` with a concurrent number. `mergeAll` wouldn't split the data into chunks, but it would only subscribe to the next observable, when another previous observable completed. Only n observables are hot at the same time.

```
function obs(n: number): Observable<number> {
  return of(n).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('Processing: ', n)),
    delay(n * 500),
  );
}

const observables$ = [obs(1), obs(2), obs(3), obs(4), obs(5), obs(6), obs(7), obs(8), obs(9), obs(10)];

from(observables$).pipe(
  mergeAll(3),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

See also stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-rcruhv?file=index.ts

With this example you can see in the console, that 3 outputs are directly printed at the start, every other processing output appears when a subscription output occured.